# Have got a problem with making a CAML Query by String contains "&"

Tags: development, query-string

Hello i have got a problem with making a CAML Query by the string which contains sign "&".

I have Got a "L&M" firm and when I choose it on DropDownList it make me error:

[image]

How to use this signs ?

Here is my Code:

```
   string kontraktNazwa = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>";
            var kontraktyWylistowanie = new SPQuery();
            kontraktyWylistowanie.Query = String.Format(kontraktNazwa, "Nr_Encji", DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
            kontraktyWylistowanie.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Nr_Encji' /><FieldRef Name='Nazwa_Encji' /><FieldRef Name='Klient' /><FieldRef Name='StatusQS' /><FieldRef Name='Stan' />";
            kontraktyWylistowanie.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
            SPListItemCollection kontraktySzczegoly = witryna.Lists["Zespolyv2"].GetItems(kontraktyWylistowanie);
            foreach (SPListItem okontraktySzczegoly in kontraktySzczegoly)
            {
                Label5.Text = okontraktySzczegoly["Nazwa_Encji"].ToString();
                Label6.Text = okontraktySzczegoly["Klient"].ToString();
                Label7.Text = okontraktySzczegoly["StatusQS"].ToString();
                Label14.Text = okontraktySzczegoly["Stan"].ToString();
```

And If it's comming to DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() it's put me error:

Error in Entity Name Line 1 Position 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` on the value received from the drop down.

Like

```
var encodedDropDownValue = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text.ToString())
```

this will encode your special characters to a format that you can add to your CAML query

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `L&M` with `L&amp;M`

One way to do this is to use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)